# XMLHTTP / HTTPRequest returning 404 response on custom error page requests

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I have a program that uses an XMLHTTPRequest to gather contents from another web page.
Problem is, that web page has cloaking custom errors set-up (ie. `/thisurl` doesn't literally exist as a file on their web server, it is being generated by the custom 404 error file.), so its not returning the page it shows in the browser, instead its showing its default 404 error response from that custom error page, in my HTTPRequest response.

By using this website http://web-sniffer.net/ I have narrowed down what the problem may be, but I don't know how to fix it.

Web-sniffer has 3 different versions to submit the request:

```
    HTTP version: HTTP/1.1 
                  HTTP/1.0 (with Host header) 
                  HTTP/1.0 (without Host header)`
```

When I use HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/1.0 (with Host header) I get the correct response (html) from the page.  But when I use `HTTP/1.0 (without Host header)` it does not return the content, instead it returns a 404 error script (showing the custom error page).

So I have concluded that the problem may be due to the `Host` header not being present in the request.

But I am using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0` and haven't been able to read the page using `HTTP/1.1` or `HTTP/1.0 (with Host header)`.  The code looks like this:

```
    Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")      
    objXML.Open "GET", URL, False
    objXML.setRequestHeader "Host", MyDomain '< Doesnt work with or w/out this line
    objXML.Send
```

Even after adding a `Host` header to the request, I still get the template of the 404 error returned by that custom error script in my response, the same as `HTTP/1.0 (without Host Header)` option on that web-sniffer site.  This should be returning 200 OK like it does on the first two options on web-sniffer, and like in a web browser.

So I guess my question is, what is that website (web-sniffer.net) able to get the proper response with their first two HTTP version options, so I can emulate this in my app.  I want to get the right page, but its only returning the 404 error from their 404 error template.

---

In response to an answerer, I have provided screen shots from 2 seperate cUrl requests below, one from each one of my servers.

[image: main host]

[image: secondary]

I executed the same cURL command, same url (that points to a site on the main host), which is `cURL -v -I www.site.com/cloakedfile` . But looks like its not working on the main server, where it needs to be.  It can't be a self-residing issue, because from secondary to secondary it works fine, these are both identical applications/sites, just different ip's/host names.   It appears to be an internal issue, that may not be about the application side of things.

Comment: It's not recommended to use XMLHTTP in a server application due to caching and some other disadvantages. In this circumstances you may get a response from the cache. Please read entire article at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290761 and do the same tests using ServerXMLHTTP to find out whether the problem is XMLHTTP or not.

Comment: Then what do you think someone should be using for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have any idea bout MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0. But from you problem statement i understand that the issues is certainly due to some HTTP header field that is wrongly set or missed out in your request.

By default HTTP 1.1 clients set Host header. For example if you are connecting to google.com then the request will look like this

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
```

The "Host" header should have the domain name of the server in which the requested resource is residing. Severs that has virtual hosting will get confused if "Host:" header is not present. This is what happens with groups.yahoo.com if you havent specified Host header

```
$ nc groups.yahoo.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 400 Host Header Required
Date: Fri, 06 Dec 2013 05:40:26 GMT
Connection: close
Via: http/1.1 r08.ycpi.inc.yahoo.net (ApacheTrafficServer/4.0.2 [c s f ])
Server: ATS/4.0.2
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 447
```

And this should be the same issue you are facing with. And also make sure that you are sending the domain name of the server from which you are trying to fetch the resource. And the Host header should have a  colon ":" to delimit the value like "**Host: www.example.com**".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well it is sending the Host header in the request, its the same host/domain as is in the URL its requesting. So, not sure what else it could be.  The weird thing is, it actually works when I do it cross-domain (from my staging server requesting the production server), but when I do it on the same server (production on production), it gives 404 error. Strange.

Comment: One best way to debug would be is to use curl command line utility. Do a curl call to the server from your staging server and also from prod, turn on verbose mode so that it will print all the request headers too. This way you can identify what is causing this issue.. "**curl -vL http://your.url**" and posting the result will be more helpful.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded cURL and took screen shots. Please see updated question.

Comment: You know what, I figured it out. Its because my Custom Errors were set-up to give detailed errors for local requests, and since the request is self-residing, it was local, and giving 404 error instead of the custom error. Anyways, using cURL help me find that out, so thank you.